# Como mudar a cor de uma div a cada 40 segundos?

Tags: javascript, html, div

Eu gostaria que uma `div` ficasse alternando as cores, duas cores de preferência. Se quiserem podem colocar mais de um exemplo. Mas, minha preferência, é que a cor mude a cada 40 segundos.

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou.

Comment: eu não tentei ainda, pode ser simple uma div no body e ele troque de cor 40 segundo, já não fiz pq só tenho deia de como se faz, mas sei q é possivél

Comment: O que você quer é algo bem simples de fazer, só dar uma pesquisada de leve. Uma dica, pesquise por `setTimeOut` ou `setInterval`. A resposta vc vai achar sozinho.

Comment: valeu cara vou da uma olhada

Comment: O que quer dá para fazer literalmente em 2 linhas de javascript, e precisa de utilizar o que o @Knautiluz indicou. Ao tentar obriga-o a aprofundar os seus conhecimentos o que só por si é bastante vantajoso

Comment: @GersonValdeir quando conseguir você pode responder sua própria pergunta, isso é bacana porque prova que você se esforçou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com jQuery de forma simples, da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["#f9f9f9", "#049fce"];//Array com as cores, pode adicionar contas quiser
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.divclass').css('background', colors[i]);
      i = (i == (colors.length -1)) ? 0 : i+1;
    },40000);//40 Segundos em Milisegundos
});
```

Ou com JavaScript puro:

```
var colors = ["#049fce", "#f9f9f9"];//Array com as cores, pode adicionar contas quiser
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('divid').style.background = colors[i];//A div deve ter um id, não funciona com class
  i = (i == (colors.length -1)) ? 0 : i+1;
},40000);//40 Segundos em Milisegundos
```

Comment: Tem a opção com JS vanila?

Comment: Vou atualizar a minha resposta

Comment: E se eu quiser utilizar em mais de uma div? 

setInterval(function(){
      $('#Divclass').css('background', colors[i]);
      i = (i == (colors.length -1)) ? 0 : i+1;
    },5000);

Comment: É só deixar as Divs com as mesma classe

Answer (score 0):

Selecione a div que deseja mudar a cor e use uma função setTimeout com o numero de segundos que precisa, no caso, 40000, use um if para fazer com que um contador esteja sempre os dois índices de um array com duas cores, veja:

```js
const colorDiv = document.querySelector('.change-color');
let counter = 0;

const colorArr = ['red', 'yellow']

setInterval(
 ()=> {
  counter++
  
  if (counter == colorArr.length) {
   counter = 0
  }
  
  colorDiv.style.background = colorArr[counter];
 }, 3000
)
```

```css
.change-color {
 background: red;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-color"></div>
```